# Reading PCM audio file is giving sometimes wrong samples

Tags: c++, audio, pcm, audacity

I have a **16 bit, 48kHz, 1-channel (mono) PCM** audio file *(with no header but it would be the same with a WAV header anyway)* and I can read that file correctly using a software such as [Audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org), however when I try to read it programatically (in **C++**), some samples just seem to be out of place while most are correct when comparing Audacity values.

My process of reading the PCM file is the following:

1. Convert the byte array of PCM to a short array to get readable values by bitshifting *(the order of bytes is little-endian here)*.

```cpp
for(int i = 0; i < bytesSize - 1; i += 2)
    shortValue[i] = bytes[i] | bytes[i + 1] << 8;
```

**note**: `bytes` is a `char` array of the binary contents of the PCM file. And `shortValue` is a `short` array.

2. Convert the short values to Amplitude levels in a float array by dividing by the max value of **short** (32767)

```cpp
for(int i = 0; i < shortsSize ; i++)
    amplitude[i] = static_cast<float>(shortValue[i]) / 32767;
```

This is obviously not optimal code and I could do it in one loop but for the sole purpose of explaining I separated the two steps.

So what happens exactly is that when I try to find very big changes of amplitude levels in my last array, it shows me samples that are not correct? Like here in Audacity notice how the wave is perfectly smooth and how the **sample 276,467** pointed in green goes just a bit lower to the next sample pointed in red, which should be around -0.17.

[image: Audacity screenshot of a normal wave with two samples pointed out]

However, when reading from my code, I get a totally wrong value of the red sample (-0.002), while still getting a good value of the green sample (around -0.17), the sample after the red one is also correct (around -0.17 as well).

[image: screenshot of Visual Studio debugging watch showing wrong amplitude value for the red sample]

I don't really understand what's happening and how Audacity is able to read those bytes correctly, I tried with multiple PCM/WAV files and I get the same results. Any help would really be appreciated!

Comment: It's going to be really hard to help you without a proper [mcve]. Your debugging show several variables which are not explained.

Comment: what is the type of `shortValue` and `bytes`?

Comment: @MikeVine `bytes` is a `char` array of the binary contents of the PCM file. And `shortValue` is a short array. I added those infos to my question!
@Someprogrammerdude I'll try and provide that ASAP! :)

Comment: Note that it's implementation-defined if `char` is a signed or unsigned data-type. Doing bitwise operations on signed numbers could lead to problems. Make sure that the byte array is explicitly unsigned (I recommend using e.g. `uint8_t` or `std::byte` for raw byte data).

Comment: Try `unsigned char` instead of `char`

Comment: Reading the file into a `unsigned char` array instead of a `char` array solved the issue! `uint8_t` and `std::byte` work too since they're `unsigned char` as well. If anyone wants to post it as an answer I'll be glad to accept it!